# Problema al instalar fuentes con ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fuentes

Tengo un problema para instalar fuentes con ReactJS
me sale el siguiente error:

```
./src/elements/fonts/fonts.css (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/elements/fonts/fonts.css)
```

Module not found: Can't resolve './fonts/Aldrich-Regular.ttf' in 'C:\Users\Nicko\Desktop\nsn\src\elements\fonts'

Desconozco si requiere dependencias o algún tipo de propiedad aparte, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es porque tu archivo fonts.css esta dentro de la misma carpeta que tus fuentes? Ya que miro que haces `./fonts/Aldrich-Regular.ttf` y seria algo como `./Aldrich-Regular.tff`

Comment: gracias por la recomendación, probé cambiandola de lugar y nada.. cambié las rutas y nada, seguramente es algo muy sencillo de hacer y soy yo el iluso que no da con la tecla correcta, gracias por apoyarme.. seguiré buscando, si alguien sabe alguna alternativa, se lo agradezco!